# How to change TextView in Activity by delete button in RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I add an item by button Scan Now, the `public double sumCost` value incrementes by the `cost` value in the `AddItem` method and then TextView(`android:id="@+id/SumText"`) assigns this value. And How to decrease `sumCost` by the number that is in `cost` and set new text in TextView when pressing the `Delete` button? Thanks for any help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njLb8.jpg)

My full code:

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.testfirst;

...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView sumText;
    Button buttonAdd;
    List<Contact> contacts = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

        buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);
        sumText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SumText);

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AddItem("Tom", 2.45);
                sumText.setText(Double.toString(sumCost));
            }
        });
    }
    public void AddItem(String name, double cost){
        sumCost += cost;
        RecyclerView rvContacts = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts);
        rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
        rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        contacts.add(new Contact(name,Double.toString(cost)));
    }
    public double sumCost = 0;
}
```

Contact(Model class):

```
...

public class Contact {
    private String mName;
    private String mCost;

    public Contact(String name, String cost) {
        mName = name;
        mCost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public String getCost() {
        return mCost;
    }

}
```

ContactsAdapter:

```
...

public class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contact, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(contactView).linkAdapter(this);
    }
    ///////////////
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Contact contact = mContacts.get(position);

        TextView textViewId = holder.nameId;
        textViewId.setText(contact.getName());
        TextView textViewCost = holder.nameCost;
        textViewCost.setText(contact.getCost());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContacts.size();
    }


    List<Contact> mContacts;


    public ContactsAdapter(List<Contact> contacts) {
        mContacts = contacts;
    }
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ContactsAdapter adapter;

    public TextView nameId;
    public TextView nameCost;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        nameId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        nameCost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textCost);

        itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            adapter.mContacts.remove(getAdapterPosition());
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
        });
    }
    public ViewHolder linkAdapter(ContactsAdapter adapter){
        this.adapter = adapter;
        return this;
    }
}
```

item_contact.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:contentPadding="5dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:text="Delete" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

activity_users.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SumText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/scanBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scan now"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to do that would be do add a "Decrementer" interface in the adapter that it can call to decrement the total cost, like this:

```java
// Define the interface
public interface Decrementer {
    void onDelete(double cost);
}

// Define an instance of the interface to hold
private final Decrementer mDecrementer;

// Pass in a decrementer at construction
public ContactsAdapter(List<Contact> contacts, Decrementer decr) {
    mContacts = contacts;
    mDecrementer = decr;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // get views and such ...

    // Call the decrementer method when the button is clicked
    // Could set this in onBindViewHolder, or pass the decrementer
    // into the ViewHolder itself and use it there.
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        
        int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();

        Contact c = mContacts.get(pos);

        // add getCostAmount to return a double, or better yet, just 
        // store it as a Double instead of a string in Contact
        mDecrementer.onDelete(c.getCostAmount()); 

        mContacts.remove(pos);
        notifyItemRemoved(pos);
    });
}
```

and you would define the Decrementer when you create the adapter so it can access the Activity class members, like this:

```java
ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts, new ContactsAdapter.Decrementer() {
    @Override
    public void onDelete(double cost) {
        sumCost -= cost;
        // change activity TextViews and such here too
        sumText.setText(Double.toString(sumCost));
    }
});
```

**Side note**: you don't need to create a whole new adapter every time you add an item, just add it to the `contacts` array and call an appropriate `notifyDataSetChanged` method on the existing adapter.

```java
private ContactsAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

    //...
    
    RecyclerView rvContacts = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    ContactsAdapter adapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts);
    rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
    rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

public void AddItem(String name, double cost){
    sumCost += cost;
    contacts.add(new Contact(name,Double.toString(cost)));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // or a less expensive notify call
}
```